# Leaking laundry faucet, seems too well attached to pipe to come off

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge

The hot water valve for our washer started leaking after we turned it back on after replacing our washer. It probably hadn't been shut in years. If I keep it shut the leak stops, but if it's open there's a ever slight drip right at the stem.

I have done some work with regular faucets before, but this one is different as it doesn't appear to be screwed on? There's exposed threads but the faucet doesn't appear to be screwed to those. I've also heard of a packing nut that I could tighten, but from the look of it most of the apparatus seems pretty stuck in place.

[image: picture of the valve]

Comment: that is correct, it does not sppear to be screwed on ... that tap is soldered to the end of the copper pipe

Comment: @jsotola the solder would be where the threads are I take it? The part would usually screw in something but instead it's slid on and soldered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of valve can be soldered or screwed on, in your case it was soldered making total replacement more difficult. You need to replace the stem packing.  Shut the water off at the source. remove the handle from the stem. Hold the hex closest  to the wall with a wrench or vice grip pliers, You don't want the pipe to turn, when with a second wrench you unscrew the packing nut. Remove the nut along with any old packing. Bring some of the old packing to your local hardware store to match it for size. Wrap a piece of the packing around the stem in a clockwise direction. Reinstall the packing nut. Reinstall the handle. The nut needs to be tight enough to not leak by the stem, but not so tight that the valve handle is difficult to turn